# Distribute jobs via ssh

Tags: bash, loops, ssh

I want to start several jobs, each job on one machine, accessible through ssh.

So I have a file host.txt, containing the names of the machines. All machines run on the same file system. I need now a loop doing the following:

```
for i=1:nrJobs
    connect to i-th host of host.txt via ssh. (Since I dont want to store passwords, it may ask for it).
    open a new screen 
    start script.sh with parameter $i
    detach screen
end
```

Especially, I just want to start the jobs, and dont want to wait for each job to be finished. Hence I want to use screen to be able to access each job.

As an example the host.txt might be:

```
hostA 
hostB
hostC
hostD
```

Username is not needed and sudo not available for me.

My idea is to start with the following:

```
param=1
for host in $(cat host.txt) do
ssh $host 'bash -s' < script.sh $param
param=$((param+1))
done
```

So what is missing now, is how to attach and detach screens in a script

Comment: "Since I dont want to store passwords, it may ask for it" You might want to use Public Key Authentication.

Comment: Do they all run the same jobs ?

Comment: They all run the same script file, with different parameter

Comment: Id write the parameters in the host.txt seperated by a space on the same line as the serverIP and then just loop through like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
param=1
while read host; do
    screen -dmS "$host-$param" ssh "$host" bash -s < script.sh "$param"
    param=$((param + 1))
done <hosts.txt
```

Personally, I would not use Screen for this particular job (especially if `ssh` could end up asking for a password, but you want to switch to public-key authentication anyway) but this should hopefully help you get started.